# Define function inside prototype(like toString function)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

When I managed to define a function inside prototype object, but when I use foreach loop on the props I found this method as one of my props either.

I wanted to know if I can define methods like the toString() mehtod?

the hasOwnProperty() if inside the loop is not an option for me because the loop is inside a package.

Here is my code.

```
function Person (personProps) {

    Object.assign(this, {...personProps});
    console.log(this);
}

Person.prototype.sayHay = () => {
    console.log("hay");

}


const createPerson = (personProps) => {
    let x = new Person(personProps);
    x.sayHay();
    return x;
};

export default createPerson;
```

Thanks for helping.

Comment: (psst - hay is dry grass, hey is a greeting)

Comment: Look into `Object.defineProperty` https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty

Comment: "*when i do foreach on the props*" - please show us where you're doing that and why. Btw, there's no `forEach` that loops over properties?

Answer (score 1):

You can define property on the Person prototype like so -

```js
function Person(personProps) {
  Object.assign(this, { ...personProps});
}

Object.defineProperty(Person.prototype, "sayHay", {
  value: function() {
    console.log("hay");
  },
  /* 
     You can make `enumerable` property below false, 
     if you don't want it to be shown while 
     looping over properties
  */
  enumerable: true 
});

const createPerson = (personProps) => {
  let x = new Person(personProps);
  return x;
};

let person = createPerson({
  a: 1
})

person.sayHay();

for (p in person) {
  console.log(p);
}
```

This way you don't have to define `sayHay` property each time you create the object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`class`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes)

```js
class Person {
  constructor(personProps) {
    Object.assign(this, { ...personProps});
  }

  sayHay() {
    console.log("hay");
  }
}

const createPerson = (personProps) => {
  let x = new Person(personProps);
  x.sayHay();
  return x;
};

let person = createPerson({
  name: 'John'
});

for (prop in person) {
  console.log(prop);
}
```

Comment: my problem in this solution is that i dont want the Person to have functions refs. 
and also i need to send does Persons to the server side without the functions

Comment: _"i dont want the Person to have functions refs."_ What do you mean ?

Comment: oh im sorry. i ment i want the Person to have functions references*.
 i dont want a function per instance

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but look at @evolutionxbox comment, it should guide you to another solution

Comment: @GoorLavi Using a `class` doesn't create a function per instance. It's still on the prototype, just not enumerable by default.